# Getting Facebook comments from a link in Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Python Facebook SDK to access Facebook. Given an external link, I want to get the comments to that link. I do this:

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token, version='2.7')
url_id = graph.get_object(url)['og_object']['id']
comments = graph.get_connections(url_id, 'comments')
```

But the resulting value is just:

```
{u'data': []}
```

I tried this with two different links that I know have comments with no luck. Am I doing something wrong, or is this version of the SDK no longer working? This node is supposed to have a comments edge, as I understand it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
My version of `facebook` on Python 2.7 has no `GraphAPI`.  Also important is that `url` is undefined.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008

Comment: @CBroe So I did that: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=og_object{comments}&id=http://www.foxnews.com/us/2015/04/14/seattle-boss-raises-entire-company-minimum-wage-to-70000.html&access_token=<token> and the result is

`{
     "og_object": {
       "id": "1069218256443049"
    },
    "id": "http://www.foxnews.com/us/2015/04/14/seattle-boss-raises-entire-company-minimum-wage-to-70000.html"}`

Comment: @Prune url is just the string of the url I'm trying to get. The one I've been testing with is an old URL, "http://www.foxnews.com/us/2015/04/14/seattle-boss-raises-en‌​tire-company-minimum‌​-wage-to-70000.html". The only other thing I've omitted is the token, and the print comments statement. I don't know what to say about your statement that your version of facebook on Python 2.7 has no GraphAPI. Mine clearly does, as I'm successfully authenticating and getting back a valid og_object id.

Comment: It appears that I have a faulty `facebook` installation; thanks.

Comment: This URL does not appear to have the Facebook Comments Plugin embedded at all; there is only a comment section "Powered by Livefyre", which is a 3rd party service that users can _log in to_ using their Facebook account. But that does not mean there are Facebook comments made upon that URL. So what you are looking for via Graph API does not exist in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe So, if someone (say, Fox News) shares a url on FB, and then a bunch of people comment on it on FB, those comments can't be fetched? Or do I need to work from the post URL rather than the news article's link? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, those would be comments made on the Facebook post then, not the external Open Graph object.